# What's the right way to update a record using has_many, through table? Update a record doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails v6.1.4

So I got the 3 tables contacts, lists, and the bridge table between two tables called multicats.

```rb
    create_table :multicats, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :list
      t.belongs_to :contact
    end

    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.string :email
      t.string :first_name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :lists do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
```

```rb
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :multicats
  has_many :lists, :through => :multicats, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :multicats
  has_many :contacts, :through => :multicats, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When I update a record I got an error:
**ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey in ContactsController#update
Unknown primary key for table multicats in model Multicat.**

```rb
 # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1 or /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(first_name:  contact_params[:first_name], :email => contact_params[:email])
        mc=Multicat.update(Multicat.list_id,@contact.id, {:list_id => contact_params[:list]})
        # mc.update!
        format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: "Contact was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**What's the right way to update a record when it's got has_many, through a table ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Rails will assign `id` as the primary key. In your migration, the `multicast` `:id` was set to false, which result in [no primary key](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table): for `multicasts` table.

ActiveRecords needs primary_key to do an update operation. So, when you call `update` method, it will find no primary_key reference and throw `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey` error.

If you intentionally remove the `id` and want to assign another name you have to provide another [:primary_key](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-primary-key)  for your `multicast` table.

Comment: That was it. I got rid of ```false do |t|``` and it’s working now